# C# Regular Expression for pattern {!USER.####}, {{!USER.####}, {!USER.####}}

Tags: c#, regex

i have written  "`\{(?:!USER.)(.*?)\}"` regex to identity following format. **'#'** represent any character

```
{!USER.####}
```

what is correct regex to  match bellow patterns also  ? but that should not match with `{!USER.####}`  pattern

```
{{!USER.NAME}} , {{!USER.PHONE}, {!USER.NAME}}
```

Comment: What is the required output? Try [`{+!USER\.(.*?)}+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7b%2b!USER%5c.%28.*%3f%29%7d%2b&i=%7b%7b!USER.NAME%7d%7d+%2c+%7b%7b!USER.PHONE%7d%2c+%7b!USER.NAME%7d%7d+). Well, [your regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%7b%28%3f%3a!USER.%29%28.*%3f%29%5c%7d&i=%7b%7b!USER.NAME%7d%7d+%2c+%7b%7b!USER.PHONE%7d%2c+%7b!USER.NAME%7d%7d+) already captures `NAME`, `PHONE` and `NAME`, thus, it is not clear what is wrong with your pattern.

Comment: did you try anything at all?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  i want to change the pattern to identify other formats also

Comment: @InfoÁsith: And what does that mean? What do you need to get in the end? Please post your full relevant code to see what your issue is. Right now, there is just no question in your post.

Comment: Why does it work for you? Because it matches all the curly braces? Or because the `.` is escaped and only matches a literal `.`? When I post an answer, I explain what is wrong with OP approach - what should I explain here?

Comment: it gives all occurrences. Ex-:  {!USER.NAME}   {{!USER.NAME}} , {{!USER.PHONE}, {!USER.NAME}}

Comment: But [yours also matches all of them](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%7b%28%3f%3a!USER.%29%28.*%3f%29%5c%7d&i=%7b!USER.NAME%7d+%7b%7b!USER.NAME%7d%7d+%2c+%7b%7b!USER.PHONE%7d%2c+%7b!USER.NAME%7d%7d+).

Comment: @InfoÁsith: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to discard all matches where `{!USER.XXX}` contains a single `{` and `}`.

A simple solution is to capture 1+ `{`s and `}`s into separate groups, and then check if the length of either of them is more than 1. If it is, you can grab the match, else, discard it.

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/vFHcjE):

```
var str = "{{!USER.NAME}} , {{!USER.PHONE}, {!USER.NAME}}  {!USER.####}";
var result = Regex.Matches(str, @"({+)!USER\.(.*?)(}+)")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Where(x => x.Groups[1].Length > 1 || x.Groups[3].Length > 1)
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToList();
```

The `({+)!USER\.(.*?)(}+)` pattern will capture 1+ `{` chars into Group 1, will match `USER.`, then will capture into Group 2 any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first `{` that, with all 1+ of its occurrences, will be captured into  Group 3. The `.Where(x => x.Groups[1].Length > 1 || x.Groups[3].Length > 1)` line will filter out those you do not need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match, but with some exceptions that you want to ignore?
Then you can use a negative lookahead `(?!` for that.
In the regex below, the words NAME or PHONE must not be behind the dot.

```
\{!USER\.(?!(?:NAME|PHONE)\})(.*?)\}
```